# Un-use a language feature with R#

Tags: c#, resharper, c#-5.0, c#-6.0, c#-7.0

ReSharper does great job suggesting language usage opportunities, such as "Use expression body":

```
public IsEmpty {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

After using the "Use expression body" feature, it's now:

```
public bool IsEmpty => false;
```

The problem is, in a team you could be forced to use a particular language version, until all of the build environments for the team get's upgraded.

Now I could specify a desired language version in
[image: advanced build settings]

VS nicely complains about the language features when building:

[image]

Which is great, but I'm up to tedious task of fixing all those errors.

Is there a reverse of ReSharper's 'language oportunity' features, so we could downgrade language versions automatically?

Comment: I think the main problem here is that if some of your machines were restricted to using C#5, you shouldn't have been using C#6 features from the beginning.

Comment: @Abion47 the problem we are working against gravity is that we should not live on Earth from the very beginning, is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: If the human race had evolved without legs, that analogy might have made any sense.

Comment: @George Polevoy, if you put the cursor on "expression-bodied property" | Hit Alt+Enter | To statement body | "Use statement bodies in the solution" -- will it help? As for "interpolated strings" - put a cursor on such kind of strings | Alt+Enter | "Convert to String.Format"

Comment: @AlexanderKurakin Don't really understand how could I overlook that one!